Extract Shapes from an image with black background
I have a task to bulk extract shapes from an image. The image is with black background and the shapes are with white border.
The main goal is to extract the fruits from the image.

How do you that with Python?
I have a solution, but it's not optimal, i.e., it is not selected properly. I am not an expert in OpenCV, so any help would be appreciated.
I tried this code:
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os

# Create output directory
output_dir = 'extracted_shapes'
os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)

# Read the image
image_path = 'shapes.png'
img = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Set threshold of gray image
_, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Process each contour
for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    # Ignore the first contour if it detects the whole image as a shape
    if i == 0:
        continue

    # Create a mask for the contour
    mask = np.zeros_like(img)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [contour], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

    # Extract the object using the mask
    object_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, mask)

    # Create a transparent image
    b, g, r = cv2.split(object_img)
    alpha = np.ones(b.shape, dtype=b.dtype) * 255
    alpha[np.all(object_img == 0, axis=2)] = 0
    rgba = cv2.merge((b, g, r, alpha))

    # Convert to PIL image and save with transparent background
    pil_img = Image.fromarray(rgba)
    pil_img.save(f"{output_dir}/shape_{i}.png")

    # Optional: Draw the contour on the original image
    cv2.drawContours(img, [contour], 0, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# Display the original image with contours
cv2.imshow('shapes', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


But it is not very optimized. The output is not clear.
The expectation of the output should be like this example:


Find the connected component that is the background, then flood fill the rest to get a set of labeled masks.

Why are you using python 2.7?

probably isn't. newbies often slap tags on their questions without understanding the implication.

findContours with RETR_EXTERNAL, done.

Don't threshold at 127, threshold at zero or the black background value. Your figures are well distinguished from the the background. So thresholding at the background color should be adequate.

I suggested RETR_EXTERNAL. Since my comment seems to have resonated, let me demonstrate.

threshold with Otsu
morphology to close up some of the perimeters
findContours with RETR_EXTERNAL to ignore "holes" in any of the components
filtering of debris
cropping

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

im = cv.imread("5SziRWHO.jpg", cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

(th, mask) = cv.threshold(im, 0, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY + cv.THRESH_OTSU)

mask = cv.morphologyEx(mask, cv.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel=None, iterations=2)

(contours, hierarchy) = cv.findContours(mask, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# to remove some debris in the top left and bottom right corners
contours = [cnt for cnt in contours if cv.contourArea(cnt) > 1000]

That's all to find each object.
To crop:
for i,cnt in enumerate(contours):
    (x, y, w, h) = cv.boundingRect(cnt)
    crop = im[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv.imwrite(f"fruit-{i+1}.jpg", crop)

Some code to illustrate the results:
canvas = cv.cvtColor(mask >> 1, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

cv.drawContours(canvas, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)

for i,cnt in enumerate(contours):
    m = cv.moments(cnt)
    cx = int(m['m10'] / m['m00'])
    cy = int(m['m01'] / m['m00'])
    cv.circle(canvas, (cx, cy), 20, (0,255,0), -1)



greate work any idea how to make sure the leftmost greap is not cut out? dilate,blur?

that berry is part of the entire thing. the morphology operation took care of that. if that happens to be an issue for other pictures, a threshold closer to black would be a good idea too.

this code is very ugly, but should get you started. I lowered your threshhold quite a bit. I then draw the outlines in filled mode (-1) twice to get a clear mask. There should be a cleaner way to get to this, but this was simple and worked.
The second function then uses RETR_EXTERNAL to get the outlines from the clear binary image.
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob


def find_and_plot_inner_contours(image_path):
    # Load the image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

    # Apply binary thresholding
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(image, 55, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

    # Find contours
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    image_area = image.shape[0] * image.shape[1]

    # Filter out contours that are larger than 95% of the image area
    # and too small contours
    filtered_contours = [contour for contour in contours if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 5]

    print("Amount of contours detected:", len(filtered_contours))

    # Create a white background image
    white_background = np.ones_like(image) * 255

    # Draw the filtered contours on the white background in black color
    for i, contour in enumerate(filtered_contours):
      if not  cv2.contourArea(contour)>=0.95*image_area:
        cv2.drawContours(white_background, [contour], -1, (0, 0, 0), thickness=-1)
        cv2.drawContours(white_background, [contour], -1, (0, 0, 0), thickness=1)

    # Display the original and also the contours
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.title('Original Image')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB), cmap='gray')
    plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.title('Contours on White Background')
    plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(white_background, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB), cmap='gray')
    plt.show()

    cv2.imwrite(f'fruit_0.png', white_background)

# Load the first jpg image in the current directory
image_path = glob.glob("*.jpg")[0]
find_and_plot_inner_contours(image_path)
find_and_plot_inner_contours('fruit_0.png')
find_and_plot_inner_contours('fruit_0.png')

ogimage = cv2.imread(image_path)


import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the image
image_path = 'fruit_0.png'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply thresholding to get a binary image
_, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

# Find contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Display the original image with contours
contoured_image = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(contoured_image, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.drawContours(binary, contours, -1,  0, 2)

# Show the image with contours
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(contoured_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title('Contours on Original Image')
plt.show()
image_area = image.shape[0] * image.shape[1]
# Crop and display each contour
cropped_images = []
for cnt in contours:
  if not  cv2.contourArea(cnt)>=10:
      continue
  x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
  if w < 30 or h<30:
      continue
  cropped = ogimage[y-int(0.05*h):y+int(1.05*h), x-int(0.05*w):x+int(1.05*w)]
  cropped_images.append(cropped)

  # Display the cropped section
  plt.figure()
  plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(cropped, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
  plt.title('Cropped Section')
  plt.show()

# Save the cropped images
for i, cropped in enumerate(cropped_images):
    cv2.imwrite(f'cropped_image_{i}.png', cropped)




could you please add a picture of your results?

You can find and select connected component. See Mad Physicist comment.
import cv2
dilate_size=(7,7) #kernel size
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, dilate_size)
gray=cv2.imread('fruits.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
bw = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
im_close=cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
im_close2=im_close.copy()
cv2.floodFill(im_close,None, (0,0), 255)[1]
mask=~cv2.bitwise_xor(im_close2, im_close)
retval, labels, stats, centroids=cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(mask)
k=0
cropped=True # save crop image
for i in range(1, retval):
    if stats[i,4]>1000: #filter by area CC
        k+=1
        fruit_image=gray*(labels==i) # masking
        fruit_image=cv2.cvtColor(fruit_image, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGRA)
        fruit_image[:,:,3]=255*(labels==i)
        if cropped:
            fruit_image=fruit_image[stats[i,1]:stats[i,1]+stats[i,3], stats[i,0]:stats[i,0]+stats[i,2],:]
        cv2.imwrite(f'fruit_image{k:04d}.png', fruit_image)


